# I use url in action and get 404 not found but route is exist and when I use route I get error route is not defined in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, storing-data

I want a make storing orders for `speaker/book` in the database but I don't use a chart so after filling in the text field it will be inserted into the database table and only logged-in users can make bookings. Is the flow of my program logic below wrong? When I use this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('speaker/book-store') }}">
    @csrf
</form>
```

I get error 404 not found but my route in `web.php` is exist
here `web.php`.

```
Route::get('/speaker/book', ' App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create')-> name('speaker/book-create');
Route::post('/speaker/book', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store')->name('speaker/book-store');
```

But when I use route not URL like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('speaker/book-store') }}">
    @csrf
</form>
```

I get error route is not defined:

This is my `ProductController`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\User;
use Auth;
class ProductController extends Controller {
    public function create() {
        return view('speaker/book');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $order =new Order();
        $order->date=$request->input('date');
        $order->date=$request->input('time');
        $order->date=$request->button('acara');
        $order->date=$request->textarea('detail');
        Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success'); 
    }
}
```

**Models Order**

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    public function user() {
        return $this-> belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Models User I add like this:

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

Comment: clear your route then try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: the naming convention of these routes is not good practice follow without slashes e.g - "speaker.book_create" as the name

Comment: <form method="POST"  action="{{ url('speaker/book-store') }}">
  @csrf
 </form>

In this example the URL is wrong

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh hi sir, thanks in advance for your help. I have changed like this speaker.book_create in name web.php and my url is like this <form method="POST" action="{{ url('speaker.book-store') }}" >.
I keep getting 404 not found .
Btw I edited this on a live server after hosting, and I'm confused how to run the command line

Comment: you are doing wrong again it should be like that "{{ route('speaker.book-store') }}"

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh when i use route i get eror Route [speaker.book-store] not defined. :"

Comment: existing web.php please provide here

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh  // SPEAKER
Route::get('/speaker/book', function() {
    return view('speaker/book');
});    and    Route::get('/speaker/book', ' App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create')->name('speaker.book-create');
Route::post('/speaker/book', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store')->name('speaker.book-store');    before that i make contact-us like this Route::post('/contact-us', [ContactUsController::class, 'store'])->name('contact-us-store');?> and it's work fine. I confused in my book.blade,php i use form action  {{ route('speaker.book-store') }} i get route not define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Routes you defined is not proper the URL should not be same

**OLD Routes**

```
Route::get('/speaker/book', function() { return view('speaker/book'); }); 

Route::get('/speaker/book', ' App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create')
 ->name('speaker.book-create');

Route::post('/speaker/book', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store')
 ->name('speaker.book-store');
```

**New Routes - Try this routes**

```
Route::get('/speaker/book/view', function() { return view('speaker/book'); });

Route::get('/speaker/book/create', 
'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create')->name('speaker.book-create');

Route::post('/speaker/book/store', 
'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store')->name('speaker.book-store');
```

In Action for book.blade.php

```
 {{ route('speaker.book-store') }}
```

Understand One thing even if providing a route to the form-action , while posting the form it gets converted to URL because of your same URL define it's getting conflicted

Answer (score 0):

update these routes .

```
Route::get('/speaker/book',[App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'create'])-> name('speaker/book-create');
Route::post('/speaker/book', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'store'])->name('speaker/book-store');
```

then run `php artisan optimize`

i hope you will get your solution .